# sql query simplification with less burden

Tags: sql

I need to simplify the following query as much as possible either by using joins or any other way...

```
select polid
  from polver
  where idmkey = 'idm3'
    and polid in ( select polid
                     from polver
                     where idmkey = 'idm2'
                       and polid in ( select polid
                                        from polver
                                        where idmkey='idm1' ) );
```

Comment: Why do you need that? Knowing this is important to answer.

Comment: @usr - It appears that the table allows 1:many or many:many between polid and idmkey.  The op therefore wants all polid's that are associated to all three idmkeys `('idm1','idm2','idm3')`.  It's a shame the OP hasn't clarified that though.

Comment: Hey Dems, you got exactly that what i am trying to get the result. Do you have better query for this scenario.?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a group by:

```
select  polid
from    polver
group by
        polid
having  max(case when idmkey = 'idm1' then 1 end) = 1
        and max(case when idmkey = 'idm2' then 1 end) = 1
        and max(case when idmkey = 'idm3' then 1 end) = 1
```

Comment: In  ms-access, replace `case when idmkey = 'idm1' then 1 end` with `iif(idmkey='idm1',1,0)`

Answer (score 3):

```
select polid from polver
where idmkey in ('idm1', 'idm2', 'idm3') 
group by polid
having count(distinct idmkey) = 3
```

Comment: What if one polid is associated with the same idmkey value multiple times?

Comment: `count(distinct idmkey) = 3` would fix that

Comment: @Andomar - Shhhh, I wanted JuergenD to do it ;)

Comment: @Ramesh.kbvr: Yes, if you use `count(distinct idmkey)` it will count correctly.